# existingObjectWithID don't return managedObject in child managedObjectContext, why?

Tags: core-data

**1)** Creating a managed object, and save it inside its managedObjectContext in `mocOut`. `mocOut` is child of a child of the main managedObjectContext

```
var dmo: NSManagedObject? = nil
mo = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("xxx", inManagedObjectContext: mocOut) as? NSManagedObject
let success = mocOut.save(nil)
```

**2)** Creating a child managedObjectContext of `mocOut` called `mocIn`

```
let mocIn = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
mocIn.parentContext = mocOut
mocIn.performBlockAndWait({
let managedObject = mocIn.existingObjectWithID(dmo!.objectID, error: nil) // <- return nil
```

Why `existingObjectWithID` method returns nil? I created and saved managedObject in the outer managedObjectContext.

**UPDATE**

After the save call I have added two more save calls to save the upper MOCs, also the main MOC with persistentStore. Saves are performed, I can  see the record is **written out** to the database, but still the `existingObjectWithID` method **cannot fetch** record in `mocIn`.

Comment: Show how you obtain the `managedObjectID`.

Comment: Show how you obtain the managedObjectID.

Comment: like this: dmo!.objectID

Comment: Look like you need to check if mocIn, objectID, parentContext etc. are maybe `nil`. After creating objectID, check if you can retrieve the object with it right away. - Also, I think you should try to catch the error, rather than using `nil`.

Comment: I checked I can fetch managedObject directly after saving with existingObjectWithID

Comment: I checked errors, they are all nil.